# Using logarithms with PuLP?

Tags: python, linear-programming, logarithm, pulp

I am using the package PuLP to solve several linear programming problems. *Note: I am a beginner in LP.*

In order to express one of the constraints for my LP problem as a linear expression, I used a logarithmic transformation. In detail, my constraint has the following form:

`log(variable 1) + log(variable 2) <= log(1.2) + log(variable 3)`

Is it possible to write this into PuLP?

I tried the following as a test:

`model += np.log ( pulp.lpSum( [x[i]*label_values[i]*female[i] for i in students ] ) ) <= np.log(1.2)`

and received the following error: `TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type LpAffineExpression which has no callable log method` It looks like the numpy log method isn't interfacing well with pulp.lpSum.

Any idea on whether or not this is possible?

Thanks!

Comment: PuLP/Linear_programming works with linear functions. `log` is not a linear function, so it should not work.

Comment: I see -- is there a different Python package I could use for which this would work?